# getFont() method

Tags: java, awt

I just wanted to ask a question about the getFont() method, which is in java.awt.Font. I don't understand why the getStyle() is undefined for type string, although it actually should work with strings. In API it says it takes an integer as argument.

```
    import java.awt.Font;
//import java.util.*;
public class NotEqual 

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.println("Write something ");
    String sentence  = "The sentence";
    //int x = 2;
    //System.out.println(sentence.getFont());
    //System.out.println(sentence.getSize());
    //System.out.println(sentence.getStyle());
    System.out.println(sentence.getFont());

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You don't call getStyle on an int or a String, but only on a Font. As the API states, it returns an int. What exactly do you mean "it actually should work with Strings". And my API states that this method takes no arguments. Please clarify your question for me.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Why would `getStyle()` *take* any arguments at all? And what does this have to do with the `getFont()` method? Why do you think styles "should" work with strings?

Comment: I'm confused. `getStyle()` returns an int, and doesn't take any arguments. How do you mean that it should work with strings? And what does `getFont()` have to do with anything? Can you post some sample code that you'd expect to work?

Comment: It appears that this question is confusing a lot of us.

Comment: I suspect the OP has some confusion, but why the down-vote?  Would the down-voter care to share their reason?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I think a downvote makes sense - it's a really badly asked question. "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - sounds pretty correct to me...

Comment: If he takes the time to clarify the question, likely the down-vote will go away, and probably get replaced with up-votes. So far we've heard nothing from the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

Style is a integer, defined by the constants Font.PLAIN, Font.BOLD, or Font.ITALIC.

From the docs:

> Returns the style of this Font. The style can be PLAIN, BOLD, ITALIC, or BOLD+ITALIC.

It is never a string.  A string is not one of the accepted values.  (It never has been.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because Strings don't have fonts. Period. All they are are lists of chars with supporting methods and properties, but no font. To see what methods you can call on String, look at the API as that is the final arbitrator of what you can and cannot do with them. In fact, if you search the text of the String API, you won't even find the word "font" present anywhere.

I still don't understand the part about it "In API it says it takes an integer as argument" though.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be that the `int` return value is easier to interpret than either `BOLD+ITALIC` or `ITALIC+BOLD` (same style, same `int`, different `String`).

---

Noting also that arguments can be overloaded but return types cannot, it could be argued that the `int` is the better value to return.